# Command to find how many different name there is in a file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command

I have a file with with the name, gender and year of birth of a group of kids (+5xxx) and I need to find how many different name there is. Here's a sample of how the file is :

```
2008 fille Avah     
2008 fille Carleigh     
2008 fille Kenley     
2000 garçon Michael     
2000 garçon Joseph
```

I tried this command `(cat prenoms.txt | cut -c 12-30 |uniq |wc -l)`, but the problem is that the when I cut the first 12 or 13 rows it never gives me only the names because the genders are different size word. Can anyone help ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact problem or error. A description alone is not enough. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use space as delimiter like below .

```
$cat sample.txt |cut -d" " -f3 |sort|uniq
Avah
Carleigh
Joseph
Kenley
Michael
```

or you can use awk

```
$awk '{print $3}' sample.txt |sort|uniq
Avah
Carleigh
Joseph
Kenley
Michael
```

Please try and let us know the result . cheers

Comment: It works. Just to be sure, you use cut -d" " to use " " as a delimiter and -f3 to cut the 3th row ? Thank you so much!

Comment: welcome. right, -d for delimiter -f field. in your file 3 fields are there and name is third field.Please accept the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that I had to accept the answer. Pretty cool system! cheers